# Website won't scroll down

Tags: html, css, scroll

My website works on a 15 inch laptop, but whenever I resize the browser, some of the information on my website 'disappears', as I am unable to scroll (scrollbar won't appear).

I'm experiencing this problem for two of my websites (they're part of a school project).

On the first website, the sticky footer covers the content when the website is being viewed in a smaller browser window. I managed to get a scrollbar for the container part (everything except for the header and footer), but I need the scrollbar to appear on the very right side of the website, outside of the container. (only the footer will be fixed, the header will be scroll-able as well).

http://sophisticateddesign.nl/cfreport/index.html

On the second website, I need the header and butterfly to stay fixed and for everything else to be scroll-able.

http://sophisticateddesign.nl

I'm wondering if there's an easy solution as I don't have much time left for these websites to finish..

Answer (score 22):

Remove `overflow: hidden` in html

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}
```

Remove `position: absolute` for .Wrapper

For second site:
You added your main content inside `header` with `position: fixed; height: 50px;`. It's the problem.

Comment: it works for the second site, thanks! 

but the first site still isn't working, the scrollbar appears inside of the container and it's supposed to be in the body, scrolling everything except the footer..

Comment: I changed the answer.

Comment: well, the scrollbar does appear when I remove the absolute position, but the whole site gets messed up: http://i.imgur.com/iIg5nak.png?1

Comment: Yes but you can see what wrong and can edit your code. Try to see in your .row and .wrapper again. Why do you use `height: 100%`. Try remove it.

Comment: I tried some things to make it work, removing the absolute position for the wrapper didn't work so I tried finding a different solution. It seems to be working now, except for the bottom row, the middle part of it isn't 100% in length and I can't seem to find what's causing this problem. (the white background isn't covering all of the div, you'll see this when you resize the browser): http://sophisticateddesign.nl/cfreport/index.html

Answer (score 3):

Yeah I just tried this out if you need something to overflow the sides you should use

```
html{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

instead of using just overflow.

|| For anyone who encounters this problem in the future. ||

Answer (score 1):

You have these **CSS** properties to your **HTML** tag.

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 960px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Try changing **overflow** to **overflow: scroll**

Comment: yes, when I do that there's still no scrollbar on the right, just in the container div..

Answer (score 0):

You have these CSS properties to your HTML tag.

```
html{
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```